# How to write crystal report formula condition correctly

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010, crystal-reports-xi

please correct my report formula condition. Im using this formula at Record Selection Formula in crystal report.

```
if {?AccFrom} <> "ALL" then ({GL_Transactions;1.DRACC} IN {?AccFrom} TO {?AccTo}) OR 
                            ({GL_Transactions;1.CRACC} IN {?AccFrom} TO {?AccTo}) ELSE TRUE
```

If im using this formula, it's only works for 'ALL' selection parameter only. But if i insert {?AccFrom} = 1111 and {?AccTo} = 1111, the result is blank. No data will appear.

Comment: what is datatype of `{GL_Transactions;1.DRACC}`

Comment: Copy paste below code in notepad, you should see formatting.. Basically, I couldnt find the result of your condition. see comment in code.

if {?AccFrom} <> "ALL" then 
    (
        if ({GL_Transactions;1.DRACC} IN {?AccFrom} TO {?AccTo}) OR ({GL_Transactions;1.CRACC} IN {?AccFrom} TO {?AccTo}) THEN
            // What goes here??? Your code doesnt have that.
    )
ELSE TRUE